# Check if process is hung via bat file

Tags: windows

So we are running a program on a specific pc to feed music to our phone lines. Every so often the program times out with "Cant connect to the internet". However all we need to do is to click the radio button and it resumes fine. The problem is as it only feeds the phone lines we never know when it has hung.

Currently I am closing and restarting the program thru a task at timed intervals. But as the issue happen randomly as far as I can tell I still end up with no music for 1/2 to 45 min.

I have tried several power-shell and bat scripts but I have not been successful. Can anyone assist?

Is it possible to check memory and cpu usage to check if it has "HUNG" and if so restart it?

Thanks -EDS

Comment: _Not an answer per se_ Have you considered finding Open Source music in the Internet Archive, downloading suitable music, then playing the music from a local drive? Would solve the Internet connection issue in one swell foop as well as protect you from ASCAP and BMI sending you a writ for commercial use of music without payment of royalties..

Comment: What is the program? Is it publically available?  A more elegant solution would require a little more insight into the application.

Comment: I worked with a telephony guy who'd set up an IVR system for my wife's office call center. Their setup used just a regular CD player to play hold music constantly on repeat. Could you just pipe audio from a dumb device like that into the line instead? Could be a lot simpler. If that's not viable you might check to ensure network connectivity from the PC is good, e.g. ensure the PC isn't powering the NIC off to save power or otherwise interrupt connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Have an app monitor the output of the sound card every 10 seconds or so.

Use [sleep](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sleep-invocation.html#sleep-invocation) from [GNU Core Utilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) in a script to recheck periodically.

If no sound card output, kill process, restart new instance of player.